# Azure Power BI Embedded

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

I have an issue that I don't know the work around yet.  I have subscribe to Azure using my Google Email.  At work, I have Power BI Pro install using my work email.  I am trying to do a proof of concept where I can use Power BI Embedded.  Now that I want to create a user in my Azure Active Directory for my proof of concept, I cannot create the user using my work email address because the domain isn't available?  Any guidance ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Now that I want to create a user in my Azure Active Directory for my proof of concept, I cannot create the user using my work email address because the domain isn't available*

Of course, you cannot create a user with your work email address. I have a domain called xxx.com, and I create a user called hello@xxx.com. You are on Azure, and you try to create an email called helloagain@xxx.com will not work because, although it is your Azure account (it does not matter if you used your gmail or not), the domain xxx.com still belongs to me, so only I can create new users.

So, yeah, you won't be able to do that.

If you wish to practice, create a new user in the domain that is already available in your Azure subscription. Build your proof of concept and then replicate what you learnt over there.